# Does WordPress have something like Drupal's DB API?

Tags: wp-query, database, wpdb

That is, the ability to write database queries like:

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
$query->condition('u.uid', 0, '<>');
$query->execute();
```

I'm converting a Drupal site to WordPress, and have kinda gotten used to this style.  Any recommendations?  Thanks!

Comment: Note that recommendations are off topic here. Is it the ability to create database queries or that specific style of interface that you're asking about? Generally in WordPress writing raw queries is considered a code smell and bad practice for most cases. Built in classes such ass `WP_Query` or `WP_User_Query` combined with custom post types, taxonomies, and post meta are intended as the building blocks, not custom tables. By querying WP tables directly you bypass lots of features and checks and deprive plugins and the theme of chances to integrate

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's the [`wpdb` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/). Some examples can be found [for e.g. here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A385+is%3Aanswer+wpdb).

Then there's the `global $wpdb` object that contains results and other parts, set based on the current routing.

You can also utilize the [`WP_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) which is more common. There's a default `global $wp_query` object and the `$wp_the_query`(?) intermediary object, that holds the default routing based result. You can use `WP_Query` basically like any old school query builder and call it a poor mans ORM.